# How to perform an action each time a class is loaded or a resource is found?

Tags: java, profiling, classloader

I have this class:

```
public class UnusedJarDetector {
    public static void onDefineClass(Class<?> clazz, ClassLoader classLoader) {
       ...
    }
    public static void onGetResource(URL url, ClassLoader classLoader) {
       ...
    }
...
```

And to call these methods I had to patch `java.lang.ClassLoader` from jdk1_6_0_31 and add it to bootstrap. But of course the patched class doesn't work with other JRE versions.

upd: is it possible to launch java in profile mode and process the return values of `defineClass()` and `getResource()`?

```
--- ClassLoader.java.orig       2014-08-07 11:57:47.851455900 +0400
+++ ClassLoader.java    2014-08-07 12:00:55.045096600 +0400
@@ -612,7 +615,9 @@
                                         ProtectionDomain protectionDomain)
        throws ClassFormatError
     {
-         return defineClassCond(name, b, off, len, protectionDomain, true);
+       Class<?> clazz = defineClassCond(name, b, off, len, protectionDomain, true);
+       UnusedJarDetector.onDefineClass(clazz, this);
+        return clazz;
     }

     // Private method w/ an extra argument for skipping class verification
@@ -1001,6 +1006,7 @@
        if (url == null) {
            url = findResource(name);
        }
+       UnusedJarDetector.onGetResource(url, this);
        return url;
     }
```

Comment: This library may help you: http://www.jppf.org/doc/v3/index.php?title=Class_loading_in_JPPF
Using this you can create `ClassLoaderListener` and Use a `ClassLoaderEvent`.

Comment: it's just a boring custom classloader with callbacks.

Comment: It could be achieved with Eclipse conditional breakpoints, but local var names are stripped in JRE

Comment: Can you just subclass the loader and override the methods?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it, I just suggested a library I found.

Comment: is it possible to launch java in profile mode and process the return values of defineClass() and getResource()?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this using [java.lang.instrument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html). A project called "loosejar" by Kyrill Alyoshin uses java.lang.instrument to do what I think you are trying to do here, exposing its results via JMX so you can see them as the app is running using jconsole or jvisualvm. See [this blog entry](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2008/02/do_i_really_nee.html).